# how to get count of distinct row in mysql without using DISTINCT keyword

Tags: mysql

i am trying to count of the distinct row from a mysql table without using distinct keyword.
i am able to get the number of duplicate row but not total count

```
mysql> select customer_fname, count(1) from customers group by customer_fname;

+----------------+----------+
| customer_fname | count(1) |
+----------------+----------+
| Mildred        |       26 |
 ........................
 .......................
| Wayne          |       29 |
| William        |       98 |
| Willie         |       28 |
| Zachary        |       34 |
+----------------+----------+
200 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

mysql>

i should get the count as 200.

Comment: What would your desired output look like. BTW I'm sure you could illustrate your question with far fewer rows.

Comment: Why are we entertaining these type of question? @satya what is wrong with distinct ?

Comment: the interviewer asked me this question.

Comment: @P.Salmon my desired output is 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use count(*)

```
select customer_fname, count(*) 
from customers 
group by customer_fname;
```

and if you need  the duplicate

```
select customer_fname, count(*) 
from customers 
group by customer_fname
having count(*) > 1;
```

for the total count without distint keyword then you could use a subquery

```
select count(*) from  (
select customer_fname, count(*) 
from customers 
group by customer_fname) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the subquery, can it be possible with out subquery.

Comment: @satya you could make a view out of the subquery, and then count the view, if your programming language does not support subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Using `count(distinct` you can get the unique name count as below:

```
select count(distinct customer_fname) as uniquenamecount
from customers;
```

Comment: the OP require .. "without distinct keyword"

Comment: i want the count with out distinct keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are after found_rows(). for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int);
insert into t values 
(1),(1),(2),(2),(2);


select sql_calc_found_rows id,count(*) from t group by id;

+------+----------+
| id   | count(*) |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        2 |
|    2 |        3 |
+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)


select found_rows();

+--------------+
| found_rows() |
+--------------+
|            2 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows